# How to change UI language programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to change UI language by code, myself, and not rely on phone's language. (I have selected supported languages in apps properties, and also have `AppResources.resx` for each language)

I thought here is where the language changes in `App.XAML.cs` file:

```
RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(AppResources.ResourceLanguage);
FlowDirection flow = (FlowDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(FlowDirection), AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection);
RootFrame.FlowDirection = flow;
```

So I changed it to:

```
RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("de");
RootFrame.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
```

But, nothing happens. just flow direction gets right to left.

Comment: <app name>.AppResource.AppResource.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful tutorial [here](http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/localize-a-windows-phone-7-application/) and the source code can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/matthieugd/WP7Samples/tree/master/SampleLocalization/SampleLocalization).

For short you can do it as follows

1. Create resources for each culture your app supports
2. Modify your project (`*.csproj`) file to support languages of your choice (if you use VS 2010 and WP 7.1 SDK)
3. Create the `ViewModel` class which manages resources and notifies UI of Current Culture changes
4. Provide proper UI clues for user to change app language (a toggle button, list or something like that)
5. Change current culture upon user interaction

Just remember to change binding mode something other than `OneTime`